# Linux / C++ Help with glade3 and gtkmm

Tags: c++, glade, gtkmm

Here is a C application source code, which creates GUI using Glade3 and GTK2+:

```
// gcc -o simple simple.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 gmodule-2.0)


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkBuilder *builder;
GtkWidget  *window1;

G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_window1_destroy (GtkObject *object, gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}

G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_button2_clicked (GtkObject *object, gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}

G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_button1_clicked (GtkObject *object, gpointer user_data)
{
    const gchar *name;
    GtkWidget *name_entry = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "entry1"));
    name = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(name_entry));
    g_print("Name is: %s\n", name);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    GError     *error = NULL;

    /* Init GTK+ */
    gtk_init( &argc, &argv );

    /* Create new GtkBuilder object */
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    /* Load UI from file. If error occurs, report it and quit application.*/
    if( ! gtk_builder_add_from_file( builder, "simple.glade", &error ) )
    {
        g_warning( "%s", error->message );
        g_free( error );
        return( 1 );
    }

    /* Get main window pointer from UI */
    window1 = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "window1" ) );

    /* Connect signals */
    gtk_builder_connect_signals( builder, NULL );

    /* Destroy builder, since we don't need it anymore */
    //g_object_unref( G_OBJECT( builder ) );

    /* Show window. All other widgets are automatically shown by GtkBuilder */
    gtk_widget_show( window1 );

    /* Start main loop */
    gtk_main();

    return( 0 );
}
```

and the glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.16"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window1_destroy"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkTable" id="table1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="n_rows">2</property>
        <property name="n_columns">2</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkHButtonBox" id="hbuttonbox1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">OK</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <signal name="clicked" handler="on_button1_clicked"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">False</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="top_attach">1</property>
            <property name="bottom_attach">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkHButtonBox" id="hbuttonbox2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button2">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Exit</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <signal name="clicked" handler="on_button2_clicked"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">False</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">1</property>
            <property name="right_attach">2</property>
            <property name="top_attach">1</property>
            <property name="bottom_attach">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Enter your name:</property>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="invisible_char">&#x25CF;</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">1</property>
            <property name="right_attach">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Now I want to code this application in C++. Can anyone give an example or tutorial using gtkmm? Or better convert this simple example for me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

I suggest that you read the [gtkmm tutorial](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/index.html).

I can bother to convert it all but it would look something like this:

```
void button1_clicked()
{
  ...
}

int main(int argc, char argv)
{
  Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);

  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("my_gui.ui");

  Gtk::Window *window1 = 0;
  builder->get_widget("window1", window1);
  Gtk::Button *button1 = 0;
  builder->get_widget("button1", button1);
  // get other widgets
  ...

  button1->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &button1_clicked));

  // connect more signals
  ...

  Gtk::Main::run(*m_main_window);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that you cannot use Glade to connect your signals when using gtkmm, you need to do that manually.

Comment: I had that exact question, if glade does the signal connecting for you or not. Thanks much.